# How can I change a variable of my javascript, then run the "onload" without reloading the page

Tags: javascript

I have a site that picks a new song every day and just uses xml docs and stuff..that doesn't matter, what matters is I would like to test tomorrows song, by changing a variable, then "emulating" the onload, so that it changes the content to tomorrows page. Is there any way to do the onload, without reloading the page(which changes my variable back)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to trigger it from your browser's console. Open the console (or Firebug) and allow the page to load normally.  Then set the new variable in the console.  Just call `window.onload()` (or `document.body.onload()` if that's how you defined it) and your function should fire with the new value.

```
// In the browser console:
yourVariable = 'tomorrowSong.mp3';
// Updated: 
// Since you have bound body.onload, use:
document.body.onload();
// Or call the function directly in the console:
onpageload();
```

It appears your variable is defined in scope of your function, which makes it difficult to change from the console. Instead, define the variable outside the function. That way, you can redefine it simply in the console

```
// Define v at a higher scope
// Outside the function...
var v;
```

Comment: @user1420493 What object did you bind the onload to?

Comment: well the commands I put in were:
v = 0;
window.onload();
and the function that onload calls is "onpageload()"

Comment: @user1420493 You need to post your code if this isn't helpful enough.  If your variable is defined in a scope other than `window`, you'll need to be more specific when you set it in the console.

Comment: @user1420493 yeah, post some code where and how you call the onload

Comment: This is all of the code you should need to help me. The rest is just if statements based on the day.
    <body onload="onpageload()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onpageload(){

    //CREATE NEW DATE
    var u = new Date();

    //GET THE WEEKDAY OF THE DATE
    var v = u.getDay();

Comment: then all you need to call is onpageload()